# Automating Print To PDF From PrintDocument In .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, printdocument

I'd like to export a VB .NET PrintDocument to a PDF automatically (i.e. without the need for any user interaction). I've been trying to find a free PDF SDK (or something similar) that will allow me to do this.
I've tried a couple of free PDF printers (Bullzip and CutePDF), both of which bring up a save dialog when the document is printed. I'd like to be able to specify the name of the PDF and save location via code, but I don't think that can be done with either of those printers.

It would be good to hear what people facing the same issue have done in the past, paid-for options included. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a PDF library and it will be able to print to printer silently.

Comment: any recommendations for a library?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to re-create my document using the PDFsharp library, which uses graphics code very similar to System.Drawing.Graphics. It's going okay, but there are a few things that have me stumped at the moment and will obviously take a while to translate. As for libraries that directly convert a PrintDocument to PDF, the only ones I've found so far are pretty expensive (Foxit and Aspose).

Comment: check out PdfViewer, it's a open source and licenced under Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install BullZip and use the configuration tool to suppress all dialogs and generate the Pdf to a predefined file (same path for all print requests).

In your code, before printing, update the PDF printer configuration file  by changing the output filename in the BullZip settings. Update the PDF printer configuration file C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\PDF Writer\Bullzip PDF Printer\settings.ini (one may expect variations on the directory path).

Comment: I don't want to have to buy BullZip, is there another open source solution u might know of?

Comment: I downloaded a free version one week ago. The link is not easy to find, It's the "Communihty edition" [link for Download](http://cdn.bullzip.com/download/pdf_free/Setup_BullzipPDFPrinter_10_13_0_2368_FREE.exe)

Comment: This certainly works, but sadly the graphics on my BullZip PDF document came out looking pretty horrible. Other printers I tried -- paid for ones -- produced much higher quality images. (This might just be a local problem. I didn't come across a quality setting looking through the BullZip documentation, but maybe I missed something?)

Comment: BullZip is installed on my home computer, but I am at the office now. I will try to have a look to quality settings when I will be back at home, i.e. in 6 hours :(.

Comment: I can't find the settings.ini file for bullzip, I've used FileLocator Pro on the entire C:\ directory and nothing shows up for bullzip, should I be concerned? I can see the bullzip in the printer options when i try to print so I'm guessing it's installed

Comment: Your "users" directory is perhaps not on C:\. You may also have a look to installation logs in the exe folder or its subdirectories and search "setting". To address the image quality, change in the Image folder of the options the resolution (in dpi).

Comment: fifamaniac04, I don't think the settings file exists until you actually create one. I had to create mine programmatically myself and save it to the file address in Graffito's original post. I discovered that the AppData folder is actually a hidden folder, so if want to create the file/look at the file via the file explorer, you need to change the folder settings (Control Panel -> Folder Options -> Show Hidden Files and Folders -> Show hidden files, folders and drives option).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues to print pdf automatically through c# web application hosted in IIS. I too have provided the solution in stackoverflow you can refer that. I'm it will help you.

[How to print to network printer through application hosted in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43363033/how-to-print-to-network-printer-through-application-hosted-in-iis/43580353#43580353)

Note: In case of Web Application or Window Service, You must have to do the impersonation if the app doesn't runs under a user who has the privilege to access the printer.