# How to automate printing to PDFLite in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to convert any file to a PDF format. I chose PDFLite since it is free open source software that can print anything to a PDF file instead of to a standard paper printer.... The problem is that PDFLite prompts the user for a filename to save the PDF as. I want to use the same file name as the file I'm trying to convert since I'll be converting one file at a time...

Q: Has anyone successfully tried to do this with PDFLite or other similar software?

My attempt is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = string.Empty;

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = ofd.FileName;
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);
            info.Verb = "Print";
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(info);
        }
    }
```

but this still prompts me for a file name/location; I can't do this manually since I want to convert hundreds of files...

Comment: To print without prompt, you may use BullZip rather than PDFLite. Refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915475/automating-print-to-pdf-from-printdocument-in-net/30925398#30925398)

Comment: If you print like this, it will print on the default printer, which is not necessarily PDFLite. It'll also use the default program registered for the file extension. Maybe that application can't even print.

Comment: Is there a way to open PDFLite from the command line with a file already specified?  That is essentially what you are doing here.

Comment: I downloaded a free version of BullZip one week ago. The link is not easy to find, It's the "Communihty edition" [link for Download](http://cdn.bullzip.com/download/pdf_free/Setup_BullzipPDFPrinter_10_13_0_2368_FREE.exe)

Comment: How do you reference the API? they have some documentation but it's not entirely helpfull

Comment: There is no real API. The approach is that of your code, i.e. executing a print process (just add to info the selected PDF printer). Modify the BULLZIP settings to a avoid prompts and "print" on a fixed named file. Before printing, update the "output" line of the settings file to define your filename. [Refer to initial link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915475/automating-print-to-pdf-from-printdocument-in-net/30925398#30925398)